# Normal Distribution,standard deviation and probability question.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

According a study, the duration of a match in World Cup is approximate normally distributed with the mean 111 minutes and standard deviation 5 minutes (including the break between the halves).

Question:
Estimate the probability that more than 30 matches in World Cup 2018 will have the duration between 110 and 118 minutes (assumed there will have 64 matches).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
X \in N(111, 5)
$$
The probability that a single match will last between 110 and 118 minutes is
$$
p = P(110 \le X \le 118) = F_X(118) - F_X(110)
$$
if $F_X$ is the cummulative dist. function. The probability that at least 30 (out of 64) lasts between these values is
$$
1 - \sum_{i=0}^{30} {64 \choose i}p^i(1-p)^{64-i}
$$

Comment: so i using this formula by keep change the i to 0,1,2,3...30?
then become 1-i=0-i=1-i=2.... ?

Comment: Yes exactly, you sum the values for every i from $i=0$ to $i=30$

Comment: ops, is a long way to calculate haha

Comment: You can use the cumulative binomial distribution as stated below to find the value of the sum =)

Answer (score 1):

Find the probability $p$ that a single match will last between 110 and 118 minutes using the [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). Then use the [cumulative binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) to find the probability of more than 30 succeeding.

Comment: so i need to count 34 times for the more than 30 matches?

Comment: Well find the probability that $\leq 30$ games last this duration: ${\sum_{i=0}^{30}} {{64}\choose{i}} p^i(1-p)^{64-i}$ and then subtract this from 1.